# Why does this pbm image behaves weirdly

Tags: image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, netpbm

I am trying to understand why I am not getting expected result from the following lines of code:

```
pix=np.asarray(Image.open(File))) #I am reading a pbm file into memory
img = Image.fromarray((pix), '1') #rewriting 
img.save("test1.pbm")

newpix=~pix #inverting the image
img = Image.fromarray((newpix), '1')
img.save("test2.pbm")
```

original image and test1.pbm(image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdLTY.jpg)) is same, but test2.pbm (image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ViVj.jpg)) isn't what I am expecting (**the foreground pixels become background ones and vice versa**). I am attaching the images here (converted to jpeg). What am I doing wrong?

Another issue is that for most of the foreground pixels in test1.pbm, the value is False. But that is not reflected in the saved image.

I converted both of these images from this original image http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/graphs/images/line_example1.jpg using Imagemagick.
[image: test1.jpg]

[image: test2.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognise which language you are using, but your original image, when converted with ImageMagick like this:

```
convert cdLTY.jpg -negate out.jpg
```

looks like this:

[image]

So I deduce the problem is in your inversion. I don't know what

```
newpix=~pix
```

does (probably complelementing it or inverting all the bits?) but I think you need to `subtract` each pixel from 255 to invert your image, so if a pixel is `10` in the original image, it needs to be `255-10` or `245` in the new image.

**Explanation**

Pixels are normally encoded with 0=black and 255=white. So, if your pixel was originally black (`0`) when you do `new pixel = 255 - original value`, it will become `255-0`, or `255` meaning it is now white. Likewise, if a pixel starts off white (`255`), when you do `255-255` you get `0` which is now black.

Comment: i'm using python and the original image, when read, returns a boolean array.

Comment: What happens if you multiply the elements of `img` by 255 before you do `img.save("test1.pbm")`? And if you then calculate each element of `newpix` as `255-oldvalue`?